# Make Excel recognize numeric fields from imported stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, stored-procedures

I have created a linked table in my excel sheet that connects to a stored procedure on my SQL server, and update it via a macro as

`Sheet.Range("TableName").ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False`

This works great, but pulls in numeric columns as text, and when my macro tries to do math with these text values it fails.

My current workaround is calling

`Sheet.Range("TableName[[#All],[NumericField]]").Value = Sheet.Range("TableName[[#All],[NumericField]]").Value`

for each numeric field, which gets Excel to recognize those fields as numeric. This works, but feels clunky.

**Are there any other (better) ways to get Excel to recognize that a field in my stored procedure is numeric?**

Comment: Does your query actually return numeric values as numbers? Are decimal separators involved? Is the data stored in numeric fields?

Comment: Excel should recognize numbers as numbers, as long as the query's metadata is saying numbers *are* numbers. Look at the stored procedure, see what it's selecting from where, verify that the tables are storing numbers as numbers, alter the procedure accordingly to cast number-as-text fields into actual-numbers, and Excel should just pick it up.

Comment: Well I'll be darned, the field is an nvarchar. Thanks! Hopefully that's the dumbest thing I'll do today.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Formalising answer from comments ...

Please ensure that the numeric fields returned from a stored procedure are defined as a numeric type [Understand the 9 Numeric Data Types in SQL Server 2008](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd424925.aspx)  (and not nvarchar) if you want Excel to recognise them as numeric.